# Airflow Custom Metrics and/or Result Object with custom fields

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

While running pySpark SQL pipelines via Airflow I am interested in getting out some business stats like:

- source read count
- target write count
- sizes of DFs during processing
- error records count

One idea is to push it directly to the metrics, so it will gets automatically consumed by monitoring tools like Prometheus. Another idea is to obtain these values via some DAG result object, but I wasn't able to find anything about it in docs.

Please post some at least pseudo code if you have solution.

Comment: Did you manage to figure out a way to push custom metrics ?

Comment: Have you  tried creating a custom [log handler](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#multiple-handlers-and-formatters) within your PySpark script? The challenge would then probably be to distribute credentials for log servers on Spark cluster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would look to reuse Airflow's statistics and monitoring support in the `airflow.stats.Stats` class. Maybe something like this:

```py
import logging
from airflow.stats import Stats

PYSPARK_LOG_PREFIX = "airflow_pyspark"


def your_python_operator(**context):
    [...]

    try:
        Stats.incr(f"{PYSPARK_LOG_PREFIX}_read_count", src_read_count)
        Stats.incr(f"{PYSPARK_LOG_PREFIX}_write_count", tgt_write_count)
        # So on and so forth
    except:
        logging.exception("Caught exception during statistics logging")

    [...]
```